# Привязать несколько TextBox к одному значению

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть TabControl и в нем почти одинаковые TabItem, в каждом из них есть несколько общих TextBox. Мне нужно как то их или синхронизировать, или сделать, чтобы к полю во ViewModel этого окна был привязан только TextBox на открытом TabItem.

Comment: Ну привяжите их все к одному свойству, в чем проблема-то? Что в этом случае не устраивает вас?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Не работает, видимо мое значение не понимает к какому из этих textbox'ов привязываться.

Comment: Тогда показывайте код и пишите что именно не работает.

Comment: @АндрейNOP на пастебин, или прямо здесь? Я новичок и не очень понимаю

Comment: Прямо тут, в вопрос, добавьте весь необходимый для воспроизведения проблемы код

Comment: Ссылка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/823254/edit) под вопросом. Всю необходимую информацию для воспроизведения проблемы добавляйте в вопрос.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Спасибо. я разобрался сам. У меня TextBox привязывались к числовому значению, а когда я забивал в них что-то, я писал символы.

Comment: Ну тогда вы должны были видеть ошибки биндинга, красную рамку на TextBox'е...

Comment: @АндрейNOP я увидел их, и посчитал, что это связано с тем, что к нему обращаются много TextBox'ов

Comment: @АндрейNOP можно другой вопрос? Как мне когда я переключаюсь  между TabItem'ами стирать все что написано на TextBox'ах внутри?

Comment: Ну теперь вы знаете, что таких ограничений нет, можно привязать к одному свойству хоть тысячу контролов

Comment: Можно. Задайте его отдельно.

Comment: @АндрейNOP "Вы можете публиковать сообщения с интервалом не менее 40 минут."

Comment: Это из-за того, что у вас пока мало рейтинга. Можете почитать пока справку, ответить на какие-нибудь вопросы.

Comment: @АндрейNOP я новичок. Мне не на что отвечать.

Comment: Напишите пока ответ на этот свой вопрос, чтобы он не висел открытым. Больше я пока ничем не помогу :)

Answer (score 2):

Никакой проблемы нет. Нужно просто привязать несколько одинаковых`Text="{Binding Value}"`